# Changing reference class in imbalanced data drastically affects the error rate

Tags: logistic-regression, glm, class-imbalance

Working on a binary classification problem that tries to predict customer churn, the data set is imbalanced with 2000 observations of non-churn cases vs 600 observations of churn cases.

On using GLM I see that when the majority class[Non-churn] is the reference level I get ~40 % error rate[confusion matrix] on both the levels [churn non-churn] but when the minority class is set as the reference level I get 100% error rate in predicting the minority class or in a way everything gets predicted as non-churn case.

After balancing the data using SMOTE the same trend continues, *how should I interpret this behaviour.* ?

Is it in a way saying that the non-churn population has users who have similar behaviour as the churners and hence the high error rate, but at the same time the non-churn users have a subset which are quite different than the churners in their behaviour and hence lower error rate when the reference class is the majority or the non-churn class.

```
Outcome on test data when majority class is set as the reference class:
Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
             0   1    Error      Rate
    0      268 419 0.609898  =419/687
    1       46 168 0.214953   =46/214
    Totals 314 587 0.516093  =465/901

Outcome on test data minority class is set as the reference class:
Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
                   1   0    Error      Rate
            1      3 211 0.985981  =211/214
            0      1 686 0.001456    =1/687
            Totals 4 897 0.235294  =212/901
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your second paragraph -- would you be able to edit the question to include the exact numbers in your confusion matrix?

Comment: @timleathart added the confusion matrix for both the cases

Comment: In what part of the algorithm do you use 1 or 0 as "reference"? For all I know about GLM, swapping zeros and ones should not affect error rate at all.

Answer (score 1):

Decision function of GLM itself does not depend on the choice of "reference level". What can probably depend is your **threshold**, and I guess it is chosen poorly.

For the problem of churn prediction, you probably shouldn't use error rate or confusion matrix at all. You can read [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/806/advantages-of-auc-vs-standard-accuracy) why ROC AUC or other metrics can be preferred to accuracy. Or if you still use error rate, choose your threshold in a wiser way than letting an algorithm maximize F1 metric for a single class.

What you need in the end is to decide for each client whether to treat her as ready-to-churn (it would certainly cost you $c_1$) or leave her alone (but if she churns, you lose $c_2$). If it is the case, you will profit from your anti-churn measures iff the *probability* of churn is higher than $\frac{c_1}{c_2}$. This is the natural threshold for your classification problem, and you can use the corresponding cost function to measure your success. Or if you don't know exact losses $c_1$ and $c_2$ in advance, use ROC AUC, which averages all the possible thresholds. And yes, ROC AUC is not affected by class balance/imbalance.